# add photo tag via graph api returns TRUE, but tag doesn't add to photo

Tags: facebook-graph-api, tags, photo

I used to be able add photo tag via graph api call. But it doesn't seem to work now. Does anyone know if it is an API change or something else?

Here are the steps I used to add photo tags

======================================

Step 1: use curl to send a graph call for add a photo tag

curl -k "https://graph.facebook.com/[PHOTO_ID]/tags/[USER_ID]" -X POST -F access_token=[ACCESS_TOKEN]

and it returns "true"

Step 2: send a request to obtain photo tags via browser and return no tag

https://graph.facebook.com/[PHOTO_ID]/tags?access_token=%5BACCESS_TOKEN%5D

Comment: Does it do the same thing when using the Graph API Explorer tool?

Comment: Yes, using Graph API Explorer gives the same result.

Comment: But when you go to the item to see the tag, you cannot see it?

Comment: That's the problem, I cannot see tags on the photo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never Mind. This is a facebook bug and they've resolved it.

http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/219863651435428?browse=search_4f1dd23884db68e10949201